# Connect through ssh and scp and type in password automatically

Tags: ssh, automation, passwords, scp

I know this question has already been asked several times but I got another problem. I have a part in my script where I connect through `ssh` and `scp` and everytime I run the script it always ask for the password. Most of you would probably answer that I should use `expect` or `sshpass` yet I don't have any of this two. I tried running:

`compgen -c`

and there's no `expect` and `sshpass` existing.

Are there any alternative commands? I would really appreciate your help. Thanks

**Update:** I also can't install any of this since I'm only an ordinary user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I logged in to server A as testuser and entered the ff command:

`ssh-keygen -d`

Do not enter any passphrase.
This will generate files in the folder `~/.ssh/`

Then `scp` the file `rsa_id.pub` (public key) to server B.

`scp ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub testuser@B:/home/testuser/.ssh/authorized_keys2`

Do the same vice versa (if you want access to both). Then you can now transfer from one server to the other without the being asked for your password.

[source](http://www.how2s.org/index.php?title=Howto_use_scp_without_password_prompt_(batch_mode,_scp_-B)&action=edit)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to set up keys for passwordless access (against the rules?), you can set up "SSH connection sharing".

Insert these lines into your `.ssh/config` file:

```
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath /tmp/ssh_%r@%n:%p
ControlPersist 8h
```

Now, when you log into a server from the machine with that config it will ask you your password the first time, and won't ask again until 8 hours of idle time have passed (so, you'll get asked once per day, usually).

What it's doing is keeping the connection open in the background, and then *reusing the same connection* for all your SSH sessions. This gives a useful connect-speed boost, and means you don't need to re-authenticate. All-in-all, it's great for accelerating scripted SSH and SCP commands.

Comment: Incidentally, even if you do use passwordless access, the speed-boost advantage still applies.